# Error in directional light shadow projection matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, directx9, shadow-mapping

I have VC++ code for DX9 that draws shadows perfectly.

```
D3DXVECTOR4 lightDirection(0.707f, -0.707f, 0.707f, 0.0f);
D3DXPLANE groundPlane(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

D3DXMATRIX S;
    
D3DXMatrixShadow(
        &S,
        &lightDirection,
        &groundPlane);

D3DXMATRIX T;
D3DXMatrixTranslation(
        &T,
        vPos.x,
        vPos.y,
        vPos.z);

D3DXMATRIX W = matWorldPerson *T* S;
if(FAILED(p_d3d_Device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &W))) return;
    
if(FAILED(pMeshRes->DrawSubset( i ))) return;
```

Then I change the calculation of the shadow matrix, and now shadows in my scene are drawn distorted:

```
D3DXVECTOR4 lightDirection(0.707f, -0.707f, 0.707f, 0.0f);
D3DXVECTOR4 groundPlane(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

D3DXMATRIX S;

float k = D3DXVec4Dot(&groundPlane, &lightDirection);
    
S = D3DXMATRIX(
        groundPlane.x * lightDirection.x + k,   groundPlane.x * lightDirection.y,       groundPlane.x * lightDirection.z,       groundPlane.x * lightDirection.w,

        groundPlane.y * lightDirection.x,       groundPlane.y * lightDirection.y + k,   groundPlane.y * lightDirection.z,       groundPlane.y * lightDirection.w,

        groundPlane.z * lightDirection.x,       groundPlane.z * lightDirection.y,       groundPlane.z * lightDirection.z + k,   groundPlane.z * lightDirection.w,

        groundPlane.w * lightDirection.x,       groundPlane.w * lightDirection.y,       groundPlane.w * lightDirection.z,       groundPlane.w * lightDirection.w + k    );
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: What were these changes intended to accomplish? Can you show us what the shadows look like before/after the change? Seeing the symptoms can help hint the way toward possible causes.

Comment: Use the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For curiosity I tried to change D3DXMatrixShadow() onto my func for calculation shadow matrix, no other reason.

```
    S = D3DXMATRIX(
        k - groundPlane.x * lightDirection.x,       -groundPlane.x * lightDirection.y,      -groundPlane.x * lightDirection.z,      -groundPlane.x * lightDirection.w,

        -groundPlane.y * lightDirection.x,      k - groundPlane.y * lightDirection.y,       -groundPlane.y * lightDirection.z,      -groundPlane.y * lightDirection.w,

        -groundPlane.z * lightDirection.x,      -groundPlane.z * lightDirection.y,      k - groundPlane.z * lightDirection.z,       -groundPlane.z * lightDirection.w,

        -groundPlane.w * lightDirection.x,      -groundPlane.w * lightDirection.y,      -groundPlane.w * lightDirection.z,      k - groundPlane.w * lightDirection.w    );
```

This is right software calculation of shadow matrix for DX9. Described here (link below).

[http://www.it.hiof.no/~borres/j3d/explain/shadow/p-shadow.html](http://www.it.hiof.no/%7Eborres/j3d/explain/shadow/p-shadow.html)

Comment: If this solved your problem, remember to click the ✅ icon to the left to mark the answer as "Accepted".